# QuickBlox iOS sdk presence problems

Tags: ios, quickblox

Having problems getting presence mechanism to work in QuickBlox iOS sdk ( 2.0.12). 
I have added two accounts to each other through corresponding calls to `addUserToContactListRequest:` and `confirmAddContactRequest:`

I can confirm that users are actually added to each others rosters seeing xmpp traffic in the logs:

`<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item subscription="both" name="xxx" jid="xxx"></item></query>`

My problem is: `QBChat`'s delegate never gets called `chatDidReceivePresenceOfUser:type:`

Is there something I'm missing to make client start receiving presence notifications?